# Set keyboard layout at login splash screen

Tags: boot, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, login-screen, plymouth

I have looked on many posts on all kind of forums and tried myself many things, for example: manipulate plymouth `rc.d` file, set as startup command `setxkbmap de`, create a boot time script in `init.d`, ... Anyway, I do not get the layout of my login screen in Xubuntu 16.04 (I think this is the `plymouth` login GUI) in German.

My Xubuntu language is English and my keyboard is German. That works fine **after login**, but at the *login screen*, when I have to introduce the password, the keyboard is English. How can I tell plymouth or XUbuntu, to get from the beginning the keyboard in a certain language (in my case German)

Blessings.